# When using wp_mail twice in a call, the second email is being sent to both recipients

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am calling wp_mail in two locations when an order has been placed on a website.

The first email is a notification to the store owner, the second email is a confirmation to the customer.

The first call to wp_mail goes to the intended recipient as expected.

The second call goes to the intended recipient, as well as the recipient of the first email.

The to addresses are definitely different.

This has only been happening since updating to 4.6.1.

Has anybody else experienced this problem?

I am sending through SMTP using the WP-Mail-SMTP plugin, however it is also happening with WP-Mail-Bank.

Any ideas would be appreciated on this one.

Comment: Share your code here..

Comment: Essentially the following in two different functions: $to = "someemail"; wp_mail($to....)